# Nodejs not working PPC64 big endian Linux machine

Tags: node.js, linux, embedded, yocto, powerpc

I have cross-compiled the nodejs for PPC 64 bit big-endian linux system.
but there is crash on starting the nodejs

```
rl> node
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

```
CPU detail:
-----------
Architecture:        ppc64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Big Endian
```

```
Binay Detail
-------------
file /usr/bin/node

/usr/bin/node: ELF 64-bit MSB executable, 64-bit PowerPC or cisco 7500, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld64.so.1, BuildID[sha1]=5af3ceba65ad39a51d7af347f33effa7f7028572, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

Is there anyone tried the nodejs or it is supported on big-endian PPC 64 Linux machine?

Answer (score 1):

well, where I know the latest versions of nodejs are not supported on Ppc64 B.E

look this issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3456